# Awk substitution within a find command

Tags: bash, variables, awk, substitution

I am working on a bash script that should find files such as

```
/var/www/templates/testdoctype/test_file.html.head
```

and return something like

```
cp -f '/var/www/sites/t/test/test_file.html' '/home/user/tmp/test_file.html'
```

my script so far looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DOCPATH='/var/www/templates/testdoctype'
INSTALL_PATH='/var/www/sites/t/test'
PKGBACKPATH='/home/user/tmp'

function find_suffix_head {
  find "$FROM/$DOCTYPE" -type f -iname "*.head" -print \
  | awk -v docpath="$DOCPATH" -v installpath="$INSTALL_PATH" -v pkgbackpath="$PKGBACKPATH" \
  '{ sub( docpath, installpath ) sub(/.head$/, "") } { printf "cp -f ""'\''"$0"'\''"" " ; sub( installpath, pkgbackpath ) ; print "'\''"$0"'\''" }'
}

find_suffix_head
```

This returns

```
cp -f '/var/www/templates/testdoctype/test_file.html' '/var/www/templates/testdoctype/test_file.html'
```

So, `sub(/.head$/, "")` works as it should, but `sub( docpath, installpath )` and `sub( installpath, pkgbackpath )` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for awk, you can do it with bash:

```
function find_suffix_head {
  find "$FROM/$DOCTYPE" -type f -name "*.head" | while read filename; do
    filename=${filename%.head} # strip suffix
    filename=${filename#/var/www/templates/testdoctype} # strip prefix
    echo cp -f "$INSTALL_PATH/$filename" "$PKGBACKPATH/$filename"
  done
}
```

From there you can just run the cp, too, rather than echoing it.

Comment: Ah! That was indeed a much cleaner solution, thank you very much!